# Haskell: readfile line by line and put into list

Tags: haskell, readfile, nested-lists

I am trying to take a file name into my program and then read the file line by line into a list of string. I want the entire file to be read before going onto the rest of the program. My file I am trying to read is also about 10K lines. I also need to check each lines length to be able to put them into different lists. I currently have:

```
stageone :: String->[[String]]
stageone xs = do
        fileLines <-readFile.xs
        let line = lines fileLines
        xss -- dont know where to go from here
```

Comment: What is driving the need to read all of the file before continuing? Is this a requirement from a professor? Are you concerned about performance? Especially since you have a 10K file this is where the Haskell lazy IO will be a benefit I think.

Comment: I will need to search the whole thing when I am working so thats why I want to read the whole file first.

Comment: But does the existence of the 8,002 element affect you finding the 3rd one?  ``findElement xs = filter (\x -> x > 5 && isOdd x) xs`` that list could be infinite, but ``filter`` can start returning results immediately.

Comment: well my plan is to eventually break each string length into its own list so when I need to search I can take the search key length and then only search the list with the elements of length. so if my key is length 5 I will only search the list that has elements of length 5.

Comment: That might not end up by the most Haskell appropriate approach. Hard for me to judge based on what I know. It might by just as easy apply your search to the result of a filter on length. Possibly more efficient too. Laziness does interesting things. Unlearning the straight forward strict evaluation thinking from say C or Java is one of the hardest parts of learning Haskell.

Comment: so if I wanted to use filter on length way how would I really do that?

Comment: Depends. Do you need the length for any computations or is it just to separate the 5 character lines from the 15 character lines? If you need the length it might make sense to have a [(Int, String)] where the Int is the length. Then you can sort based on the first field of the tuple. Otherwise you can just use ``filter (\x -> length x > y)``

Comment: Note, I am using the more verbose and simpler lambda functions instead of the more idiomatic ``filter ((> 5) . length)`` to make it easier to understand since you are new to the language.

Comment: this may be easier if we can just get into a real chat. Is that on here or would we need to do third party?

Comment: My email is my handle.

Comment: I just think we are crazy commenting on here. Also I could explain better probably through skype chat

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A simple way to read the file strictly is to use `Text`, which has a strict `readFile` by default:

```
import qualified Data.Text    as Text
import qualified Data.Text.IO as Text

main = do
    ls <- fmap Text.lines (Text.readFile "filename.txt")
    ... -- The world is your oyster!
```

By the second line of the program the entire file will have been processed already.

It's a good habit to learn to use `Text` instead of `String`, since `Text` is more efficient.  To learn more about the `text` library, you can begin [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text).

Comment: I would use text but I need to be able to search the list after the data is within it and I will be searching with a string. could I do the same line but with strings?

Comment: @tucker19 Yes, definitely!  The [`strict` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/strict) has a strict version of `readFile` [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/strict-0.3.2/docs/System-IO-Strict.html).

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Haskell. Unfortunately, your function's type signature won't work. You can't get away from the IO monad here.

```
stageone :: String -> IO [[String]]
```

is what you will end up with.

What you want to do is break up your requirements into functions and implement each one. These functions might be able to be pure functions without IO. Then come back and put them all together. This is how Haskell code is developed. Pay attention to the type signatures. If you get stumped, try to write just the signature and work from there.

How do you determine the length of a line?

How do you apply a function to each item in a list and keep the result?

How do you read a line from a file?

Once you have 10K line lengths, then what? Write them out? Print them?

Once you make the plan you can write and test these smaller pieces in `ghci`.

Good luck.

Comment: I am dumb, I should have IO there, I knew that. I know how to do most of that, I am just having issues with reading the file line by line.

Comment: Nah, we all do it when we are learning. "How do I get away from the IO  monad" is one of the biggest FAQs in Haskell.

Comment: how about we just with go reading the giant file into one list first then I could break it up into smaller lists after

Comment: That would be the proper approach most likely.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is the function in all of its point-free one line glory (or hideousness) with nary a lambda in sight...

```
module Main where

import Data.List ( sortBy, groupBy )
import Data.Function ( on )
import Data.Ord ( comparing )
import Control.Arrow ( (&&&) )

stageone :: String -> IO [[String]]
stageone = fmap (map (map snd) . groupBy ((==) `on` fst) . sortBy (comparing fst) . map (length &&& id) . lines) . readFile
```

Let's break it on down.  The top level is a composition of `readFile` and `fmap`.  We always read function composition from right to left.  The point-free argument to `stageone` is passed to `readFile`, which returns an `IO String` into which `fmap` sends its function argument to transform the `String` inside the `IO` candy shell.

This function is another composition which we read right to left.  First, we apply `lines` to the `String` to break it into a list of lines.  We then `map` `(length &&& id)` over the list of lines, which transforms each line into a pair consisting of the length of the line and the line itself.  Next, we sort the list of pairs by comparing the first element of each (the length).  The sort is stable, so the lines will remain in their original order within a run of the same length lines.  Next, we apply `groupBy` with `` ((==) `on` fst) ``, which groups runs of pairs with the same first element (the length) into their own sublists.  Finally, we apply `map (map snd)` over the list of lists of pairs.  The outer `map` iterates over the groups, and the inner `map` iterates over the list of pairs within a group, replacing each pair with its second element (the line).

Phew!